# With AWS how do I make my additional EBS volume visible from my ubuntu linux installation

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

With Amazon Web Services I set up a micro instance of Ubuntu linux, but it only comes with 8GB of space and that was not enough. So Ive created a 20GB EBS Volume and attached it to my EC2 instance but is not visible within my EC2 instance, even if I logout and ssh back in.

Is there some other step I have to do from the linux command line ?

Comment: You need to attach the new volume to your instance. You do that from your AWS console.

Comment: Ive already done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem I had to format the volume and then mount on my linux installation

i.e

```
lsblk
```

to see name of device , in this case xdf, then

```
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xdf
sudo mkdir /mnt/data
sudo mount /dev/xdf /mnt/data
sudo chmod 777 /mnt/data
```